# VBO - Drawing multiple elements with different colors

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I am trying to draw two quads using vertex buffer objects in OpenGL. They should be draw with different colors. Like you see, the first quad has a red, green, blue and yellow vertices. The second quad has different colors, but the problem is that they second quad gets drawn completely yellow. This is my code:

```
GLfloat vertices[24] = {10.0, 10.0, 0.0,  10.0, -10.0, 0.0,  -10.0, -10.0, 0.0,  -10.0, 10.0, 0.0,
                        20.0, 20.0, 0.0,  20.0, 10.0, 0.0,    10.0, 10.0, 0.0,    10.0, 20.0, 0.0 };    
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 24, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

GLfloat colors[24] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                      0.5, 0.5, 0.5,   0.7, 0.2, 1.0,  0.2, 1.0, 0.7,  0.8, 0.0, 0.45 };
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 24, colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 8);
```

This is how the quads are drawn:

[image]

The second quad is the one on top right. It should be multicolored, but it's drawn using the 4th element of the color buffer. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);` instead of `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);` Note, in your case `buffer` keeps bound and is used for `glColorPointer` too.

Comment: @Rabbid76 If you make your comment an answer I can accept it. I don't see why the question should be closed, it doesn't violate any guide line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [OpenGL 2.1 Reference Pages; `glColorPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorPointer.xml):

> `glColorPointer` specifies the location and data format of an array of color components to use when rendering. ...
>
> If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` target while a color array is specified, pointer is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store.

In your code `buffer` is bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`;

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
```

Then `colorBuffer` is bound to the target `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and the color array is defined:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```

Since `buffer` is still bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` at this point, `glColorPointer` uses `buffer`. This causes that the vertex coordinates are treated as colors and that`s what you can see in the rendering.

To solve the issue you have to bint `colorBuffer` to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
```